# My nginx redirect setting is not working

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I am having a problem with my site. Whenever I try to access my website it is not redirecting.

That means when I type the URL as financenectar.com it opens my site at financenectar.com but does not redirect to www.financenectar.com.

And one more thing, it is not even working when I type www.financenectar.com.

#### Current nginx configuration

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/financenectar/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name financenectar.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                try_files $uri =404;
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Please let me know about the changes.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts from your config to the question so that we can understand the question and answers later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any server-block that includes www.financenectar.com.

I have a few possible solutions for you.

#### 1. Solution - Just add the domain to server_name

Change the following line

```
server_name financenectar.com;
```

to this

```
server_name financenectar.com www.financenectar.com;
```

This will make the nginx configuration work for both domains, but there is no redirects.

#### 2. Solution - Add a new virtual host for redirect

Add a new server-block with the following content.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/financenectar/;
  server_name www.financenectar.com;

  location / {
    return 301 http://financenectar.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

This makes all requests to www.financenectar.com redirect to financenectar.com. If you want it the other way around, just switch the `server_name` parameter in each server-block and change the `return`-parameter in the configuration above to the following.

```
    return 301 http://www.financenectar.com$request_uri;
```

Comment: hello,Thanks for your help.

now there is another thing happening with me. at last you said that "If you want it the other way around, just switch the server_name parameter in each server-block and change the return-parameter in the configuration"

I did that but its not working....

"financenectar.com" is redirecting to "www.financenectar.com" and "www.financenectar.com" is redirecting to "financenectar.com"... And the main thing is both are showing the error saying "This web page has a redirect loop"

Comment: @AmitRawat Have you done it like this? http://pastie.org/private/pkkr39tmdszfcmbuy0iuea

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually it was the problem in wordpress. So we changed that and its fine now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @AmitRawat No problem. I'm glad to help :)